# Why can't I connect to MySQL in a container for a few minutes after starting the container?

Tags: mysql, docker

As shown below, when I create a MySQL 8.0 Docker container and immediately try to connect to it with `mysql -u root -ppass`, I get an error that there is no socket, but after waiting for a few minutes, I can reconnect and it succeeds. Is this because some initialization process was not completed and the first and second connection failed? If so, can I check the some kind of log to see if MySQL has finished the initialization process?

```sh
$ # WSL 2
$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
$ docker run -d --rm --name mysql_test -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass mysql:8.0
$ docker exec -it mysql_test bash
# mysql -u root -ppass
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
# mysql -u root -ppass
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
# mysql -u root -ppass
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
...
```

By the way, the cause of the error is that there is no socket to connect to the MySQL server, so I tried to `touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, but only got the following error, and I had to wait for several minutes to connect. `mysql start`, `mysql restart` also had no effect.

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

Comment: It takes a while for the database to start up and be ready for connections. `docker run` returns as soon as the container has started, but that doesn't mean that it's ready to use.

Comment: Oh I see. If so, is there any way to check that the MySQL initialization is finished in a log file? Can I it using `less` or something?

Comment: You can see the initialization messages using `docker logs mysql_test`

Comment: The usual approach is to either use `nc` or the command-line `mysql` tool to try to connect to the database until you succeed; there is a reasonably-widely-used `wait-for` script that packages this up.  The linked question has more examples.